# Subgradient of a quadratic plus 1-norm

Tags: subgradient

I need to find a point in the subgradient (at a certain point $x^k$) of the function
$$ f(x) = \frac{1}{2}||y-Ax||^2 + ||x||_1$$
for some kind of iterative method, ie I need to find $g \in \partial f(x^k)$. Here $y$ and $A$ are constant vector and matrix chosen respectively so that the dimensions make sense.

Is there an analytic expression of a point in the subgradient of $f$ given $x^k$?

Comment: page 7, https://web.stanford.edu/class/ee364b/lectures/subgradients_notes.pdf